# how do I get the JavaScript date version of this: "Saturday 5th November, 2016"?

Tags: javascript, date

Being scouring the net for a Javascript date version of the following:
Saturday 5th November, 2016
I've tried looking at day and month arrays... Im kinda stumped.
This particular date format I got from the php date format of: 
date("l jS F, Y").
Is there a Javascript version  of this - 
(complete with date suffix)?
any tips would be great.
cheers.

Comment: when in doubt defer to moment.js to simplify date tasks and formatting

Comment: Check out the [display docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) for moment.js

Comment: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

the closest format, try this

```
var d=new Date;
var str=d.toDateString();
console.log(str);
```

it will output like "Sun Nov 13 2016"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any JS native implementations to parse / display the format you mentioned

However, you could format this date string using momentjs. Here is an example on how you could do parse.

You could check more details on [MomentJs Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

```js
let date = "Saturday 5th November, 2016";

let formattedDate = moment(date, "dddd Do MMMM, YYYY");

let jsDate = formattedDate.toDate();

console.log(jsDate.toString());

//Convert JS Date to formatted

let jsDateObj = moment().format("dddd Do MMMM, YYYY");
console.log(jsDateObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```